# Standard (32/64-bit Universal), WebKit, Flash Plugin and Leopard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit

I have an Xcode project which builds a Cocoa desktop Browser application.

My Browser links to the standard WebKit.framework on the system (it does not embed its own WebKit.framework).

The "Base SDK" for my Xcode project is set to "Mac OS X 10.5".

The "Valid Architectures" for my Xcode project is set to "i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64".

The "Objective-C Garbage Collection" for my Xcode project setting is set to "Unsupported".

I am building my project on Snow Leopard with Xcode version 3.2.

When I build the Browser with "Architectures" set to "32-bit Universal", the Browser runs fine on Snow Leopard and Leopard (as a 32-bit process) and displays Flash content correctly.

However, when i build the Browser with "Architectures" set to "Standard (32/64-bit Universal)", I have a serious problem on Leopard. In this case, the Browser runs fine (as a 64-bit process) on Snow Leopard and displays Flash content correctly. However, on Leopard it runs fine (as a 64-bit process) *except* that it will not display Flash content. It seems the Flash plugin never loads.

Can anyone give me any advice on how to build my Browser as a "Standard (32/64-bit Universal)" so that WebKit will load the Flash Plugin on Mac OS X Leopard 10.5? Or is there some reason why this cannot work?

(NOTE: in all cases I have the latest Flash PlugIn installed on the system - 10.0.32.18)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash will not load in 64bit on Leopard as it is 32bit code.  WebKit on SnowLeopard can run Flash in 64bit because it runs Flash in a completely separate (32-bit) process.

Comment: Hm, yes but on my Leopard system, Safari is running as 64-bit while also loading the Flash plugin in a separate 32-bit process. (at least that's what I'm seeing in Activity Monitor.app)

Can't my Browser do that too?

Comment: Errr, are you sure you're on leopard?

Comment: DOH. sorry i must have gotten my screens crossed. could have sworn Safari was running 64-bit on Leopard, but it is *not*.

I see now that you completely answered my question. Thanks ollie. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the flash plugin is 32bit only on Leopard

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Flash plugin is 32-bit on both Leopard and Snow Leopard. But Safari manages to run as a 64-bit process and to load the Flash Plugin as a separate 32-bit process on both Leopard and Snow Leopard.

My Browser does that on Snow Leopard too. But not on Leopard. :(

Comment: I was wrong. Safari is not running 64bit on Leopard. see above.